# select2 and angular, how to set the selected value of one drop down to another drop down

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2

Am using `select2` plugin for a drop down. There are two form blocks. One for user address and another for billing. There is a drop down where the user can choose country(it is from ajax response), and both the dropdowns will be initialized with that value. When i check same as above checkbox, the billing country dropdown should be populated with the above chosen value.

**dropdown1**

```
    <select class="form-control sel2"  id="country_billingAddress" 
    data-ng-options="country for country in countryList" 
    data-ng-model="billingcountry">
    </select>
```

**dropdown2**

```
    <select class="form-control sel2" 
    data-ng-options="country for country in  countryList" id="country_bil" 
    data- ng-model="billingcountry">
    </select>
```

angular

```
    function copyBillingAddress() {
    if($scope.checkBoxSelected) {
    $scope.billingcountry = $scope.country;
    }
```

tried the below methods, but it the value to test is still null

```
    $("#country_bil").select2().select2("val", 'oneofthevaluehere');
```

getting this error:

> angular.min.js:114 Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

```
   $("#country_bill").val('dd').trigger('change') //no changes
```

Comment: not clear, what's the `problem`?

Comment: @manish is correct. The title needs clarity as does your post. What is the problem?

Comment: @manish -> updated the title

Comment: @divya do you have any sample to show (that would be easy to debug)?